# How can I read private key with password?

Tags: java, private-key

I would like to read private key in java which is with passphase

to create this private key I used a openssl with:

```
genrsa -aes128 -out private.pem
```

When I will try to open this file at the beginig I have:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,B01D36B426B8E9E8DFCDD8518D1A857F

dt3z+UEyeVarEL7mjEcRPXpUP3Zk/IbDJrwVhpYt95K5t4X+2+CIB/qsycp+d0Tr
NLhddUF0johgFMYfUnvNsJuo8PePE1bYH+Q1BYONoSqktHgmyR7BaZU2oQiWH6qI
```

and eof:

```
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Each my attempt finished fail. 
Most of the time I get:

```
DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=58, too big.
```

I don't know what to do with this issue :(
With private key withouth password I dont have any troubles but I stuck with this password :(

Comment: `"Each my attempt finished fail."` <= please show your attempt so we might see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I solve the problem.
I used a bouncycastle to open file with *.pem extension

Comment: Then you should add an answer to your question yourself or delete it.